# How to remove function from prototype

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
function a() { }

function initOverrides() {
    Function.prototype.apply = undefined;
    a.apply(this, arguments); // this will fail as apply no longer exists
}

initOverrides();
```

is there a way to cause typescript to remove functions from existing prototypes.

In this case I would like `Function` to have less members

Answer (score 0):

You would have to compile with `lib: []` in your `tsconfig.json` and copy and modify `lib.d.ts` into your project.

The modification of-course would be to remove `apply` from the `Function` interface.